# Angular-FormArray: Creating a table form from 2-dimensional Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, formarray

- I need to create a table form with Angular which is based on a simple 2-dimensional array of arrays.
- The data structure is simple but the data in the cells is interdependent. The single cells are accessed by indices alone e.g., `row:1`, `col:0`.
- Custom validators need to be defined on on cell-level. In addition, there may be validators for rows and columns.

I tried various ways to define `FormArray` holding an array of `FormControl`s. But I am unsure how to access the respective `FormControl` by row and column indices alone in the Angular template.

**Model**

```
[
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['c', 'd']
]
```

**FormGroup**

```
  form = new FormGroup({
    rows: new FormArray([...])
  });
```

**Expected result**

I am tried various things similar to this:

```
  <form [formGroup]="form"">
    <div formArrayName="rows">
      <div 
        *ngFor="let row of rows.controls; let rowIndex = index" [formGroupName]="rowIndex">
        <div formArrayName="cols">
          <div
            *ngFor="let col of form.get('cols').controls; let colIndex = index"
            [formGroupName]="colIndex">
            <input [formControlName]="colIndex" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: My library Easy Angular https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez/ has a simple to use table component. Demo at StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npn1p1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dabbel, if you has an Array of Array, create a FormArrays of FormArrays (sorry for the joke)

Well, imagine you has
data=[
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['c', 'd']
]

You can in ngOnInit create the formArray of FormArray like

```
//At firs a empty FormArray
this.formArray = new FormArray([]);
//with each element of data
this.data.forEach(x => {
  //x is e.g.['a','b']
  //we create a emptt FormArray
  const obj = new FormArray([]);
  //add a FormControl
  x.forEach(y => {
    obj.push(new FormControl(y));
  });
  //and push in the formArray
  this.formArray.push(obj);
});
```

or abreviated using map like

```
this.formArray=new FormArray(
  this.data.map(x=>new FormArray(
    x.map(y=>new FormControl(y))))
)
```

Well, How mannage a FormArray outside a FormGroup? If our FormArray is a FormArray of FormGroup, we make in general

```
 <!--yes we can use [formGroup] with a FormArray-->
<form [formGroup]="formArray">
   <!--iterate over the formArray.controls, that is a formGroup-->
  <div *ngFor="let group of formArray.controls;let i=index">
     <div [formGroup]="group">
       <input formControlName="name">
        ...
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Well, our formArray is a FormArray of FormArray, but remember that we using [formGroup] with an array and iterate over formArray.controls.

```
<form [formGroup]="formArray">
    <div *ngFor="let subarray of formArray.controls;let i=index">
        <div [formGroup]="subarray">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let control of subarray.controls;let j=index">
                <input [formControl]="control">{{control.invalid?"*":""}}
       </ng-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

NOTE: I use `<ng-container>` nor `<div>` to not create addicionals divs. (We can not put the *ngFor in the own input because, then, we can not have access to control.invalid

Well, as you want create Validators, we are changing a bit when we create the formGroup to include the validators, I put a "fool" example

```
this.formArray=new FormArray(
  this.data.map(x=>new FormArray(
    x.map(y=>new FormControl(y,Validators.required)),
    this.rowValidator())),this.arrayValidator()
)
```

And ours validators can be like

```
  rowValidator()
  {
    return (array:FormArray)=> {
      const invalid:boolean=array.value.
             filter((x,index)=>array.value.indexOf(x)!=index).length>0
      return invalid?{error:'must be different'}:null
    }
  }
  arrayValidator()
  {
      return (array:FormArray)=> {
        let arrayJoin="";
        array.value.forEach(x=>arrayJoin+=x.join(''))
        return arrayJoin=="abcd"?null:{error:'must be a,b,c,d'}
      }
  }
```

You can see in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhhe21?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: In a real application, we neen't use so many Validators. Take account the cost of this validator on the perfomance of the app

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation, Eliseo! You were right about FormArray of FormArray, of course. I'll just mention for the benefit of others that in this example`formArray.status` and `formArray.invalid` works with `FormArray`, too. Again, thank you for explaining it in detail.

Comment: Thank for the comment <!--yes we can use [formGroup] with a FormArray-->

Answer (score 0):

Template forms is going to make your life a lot easier here.

Just bind directly to the array itself.

```
<form>
  <div *ngFor="let row of data;let i=index">
    <input [name]="prop1_ + i" [(ngModel)]="row.prop1">
    <input [name]="prop2_ + i" [(ngModel)]="row.prop2">
  </div>
</form>
```