# Angular dynamic Form table

Tags: html, angular, forms

I am trying to build a Form in Angular so that a user can enter numbers in a table. The number of rows and columns can be different (nRows, nColumns) but not editable by the user.
The expected result should be something like this:
[image: Table Form]

For the rows I am using a FormArray and ngFor is working.
But I can not iterate over the Columns.
Maybe my approach is not good anyway?

```
// transport-form.component.ts
export class TransportFormComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'formarray';
  kostenForm!: FormGroup;
  rows!: FormArray;
  nRows = 3;
  nColumns = 3;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.kostenForm = new FormGroup({
      rows: new FormArray([]),
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < this.nRows; i++) {
      this.addItem();
    }
  }
  createItem(): FormGroup {
    let row = {};
    for (let j = 0; j < this.nColumns; j++) {
      row[`v${j}`] = '';
    }
    return this.formBuilder.group(row);
  }
  addItem(): void {
    this.rows = this.kostenForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    this.rows.push(this.createItem());
  }
}

// transport-form.component.html
<div [formGroup]="kostenForm">  
<div formArrayName="rows"  
  *ngFor="let row of kostenForm.get('rows')['controls']; let i = index;">  
  <div [formGroupName]="i">  
    <!-- <ng-container *ngFor="let control of row.controls; let j = index">
    <input formControlName="v{j}">??? 
</ng-container> Does not work -->
<!-- Workaround to demonstrate expected output: -->
    <input formControlName="v0">  
    <input formControlName="v1">  
    <input formControlName="v2">  
  </div>  
</div>  
</div>  
{{ kostenForm.value | json }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment due to my low reputation, so I add an answer.

Long story short, if you have an Array of Array, you can create a FormArrays of FormArrays.

You can find all the explanations in the accepted answer of this post:

[Angular-FormArray: Creating a table form from 2-dimensional Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419245/angular-formarray-creating-a-table-form-from-2-dimensional-javascript-array)

In the post he use a 2x2 data array, but I think you can adapt it to your needed.

Comment: Thx I tried this example first but the code from stackblitz gives me an error: "property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl"